# Is there a way to see the functions inside a C/C++ archive (.a)?

Tags: c++, c, binary, unix-ar

We have a situation where (simplified):

1. `test()` exists in `source.c`
2. `source.c` compiles to `object.o`
3. `object.o` gets linked into archive `archive.a`
4. `archive.a` gets compiled into final `binary`

We are attempting to change the name of `test()` to something else. But the linking step in (4) says the new method signature does not exist. Using `gobjdump` we see for certain the new renamed method exists in `object.o` (it is in the same SECT as other methods and is not UND).

We can see for certain that the `object.o` exists in `archive.a`. However, we are not certain (because of the complicated build system) that `archive.a` contains the method.

**TL;DR: Is there a way to see inside an archive file and list the functions of a particular binary object inside it?**

Comment: Is this C, or C++? C doesn't have "methods" nor "objects" in this regard.

Comment: This is actually a open source library of C methods that are being put into the archive but compiled into a C++ project.

Comment: You can use the `nm` tool to list all the functions found in the library.

Comment: If you are linking `archive.a` into your binary, and the linker complains about an unknown function, then that function is not in `archive.a`.  At least, not in the copy of `archive.a` that you are including in the link.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is exactly what we were figuring, and we were trying to see if there was a way to solve this with the 'ar' tool. I will try the 'nm' tool now.

Comment: Well, using `nm` we have confirmed the new method does exist in the archive:
`00000000000076f0 T __Z14svm_get_nr_sv2PK9svm_model`
However, g++ is still complaining that it can't find it...

Answer (score 2):

Use `nm`.  Assuming Linux, [here's the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm).